# Developing large service fabric application

Tags: c#, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

We are developing an application on service fabric and it is getting larger with time, more code and more service types. Each developer of the team uses local cluster to develop and debug.

The problem is that the build time + local deployment time gets around 15 minutes sometimes (depends if SF is doing application refresh or not) which is frustrating from a developer perspective.

I want to reduce the build and deploy time. What is the recommended pattern for large applications. Should I consider some kind of build-farm & a remote development cluster ?

*Note: We are using 'Refresh Application' debugging mode. This does not resolve the problem as sometimes SF chooses to re-deploy the whole app.*

Comment: This gets deep into how services are deconstructed; if you're not deconstructing your services along DDD "bounded contexts", that's where I'd start; combining services or pulling them apart according to those bounded contexts; next is figuring out what services are needed to do which actions in the system. If all services need to be up to be able to debug anything in the system then there's a giant coupling issue.

Comment: I could go on, but long story short: how the services decided to be created is important and may even negate the need to do what you're looking for.

Comment: We are considering loose coupling between our services but I never actually tried to enable/disable a service while developing on service fabric. I think it is pretty dirty since I have to alter the application manifest file each time. Do you have any clues on that ?

Answer (score 2):

Use 'Refresh Application' as the Application Debug [Mode](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio.md#application-debug-mode).

I recommend you create multiple small applications that can be deployed and upgraded separately. If you're using [SF remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting), the built-in retry logic will allow for some remote downtime.

**But** instead of doing [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) calls, see if you can use the [pub/sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern. (See [this](https://github.com/SoCreate/service-fabric-pub-sub) OSS project). This will allow indefinite remote downtime (decoupling services), without the caller having to wait around for an answer. Note that the downside of this decoupling approach is [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency).

Comment: Sir, we are already am using 'Refresh Application' mode to debug. Using multiple applications is an architecture change. Can you provide pros/cons for developing multiple application types vs multiple service types ?

Comment: An application is no more than a composition of services. I would say an application type doesn't define architecture, just deployment. And that's exactly what you're having troubles with, right?

Comment: I did already re-think my comment after posting it. You are actually right. I will consider this, but it is going to take sometime to verify and accept your answer.

Comment: Some links to complement the answer:
 - a brief explanation why you should [choose an application to service packaging model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/microservices/service-fabric#choose-an-application-to-service-packaging-model).
 - domain analysis for breaking down a monolith into microservices is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/model/domain-analysis)